# Articles - When don't we use them?

Tags: articles

Why don't we use any articles before the countable noun "*chairman*" in the following sentence?

> Potts was appointed ***chairman*** of the education committee.

or

> ***Camera*** was invented by X.

I searched the Internet and came across some rules, but I wasn't able to put these particular ones into any categories.

And I know that we don't use any articles when we use possessive adjectives, e.g.

> This is my ***book***.

But again I didn't see this rule in the websites I surfed. I would appreciate it if you could link me to a good reference.

Thanks

Comment: Collins Cobuild have produced a 100+ page monograph on the usages of the articles in English. You may need to order it from an internet supplier, and it may be out of print. // Just one facet: _The television is broken_ (article with count-noun usage) but _Television seems to be getting more and more biased towards pro-badger groups_ (mass-noun usage) (though I know there are exceptions to this rule-of-thumb).

Comment: The articles and possessive pronouns are two subsets of determiners (not adjectives). Determiners specify the context of the  noun they attach to in some way (unlike adjectives, which mention an attribute of the referent). 'The my book' and 'That her book' are probably over-specified. 'A my book' is not used; 'a book of mine' is idiomatic. [Wikipedia's article on English Determiners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners) gives more 'rules' but without much explanation: Combinations of determiners
Determiners can be used in certain combinations. Common examples are listed below: ...

Answer (score 1):

You certainly **do need** an article with ***The camera was invented by XYZ***

As regards your first example, the article is optional. You could say ***Potts was appointed the chairman...***, but it is perhaps more usual to leave it out.

You have no need of an article where you use a possessive pronoun.

I'm afraid that as I am a native speaker I have no references to which I can link you.

Comment: Why the camera as opposed to a camera? We are talking about camera as a concept here, not some specific camera? Just trying to understand

Comment: That is why you need *the*. If you said *a camera* it would mean that X invented just one camera. But if the person concerned invented cameras in general, it would be correct to say that they invented *the camera*. *The* in this instance refers collectively to all cameras.